# What is difference between putting a macOS app as "open at login" and putting a macOS app in "allow in the background"?

Tags: macos, swift

I can see on my mac there are some apps like Google Chrome that launch automatically when I start my Mac and also I can see apps like Magnet which it is not in auto launch but in allow in background.

These 2 different apps both are ready to use without having to clicking on app to run it, so what is difference between them? If Magnet can be used when I start my Mac without clicking on app why isn't Google chrome there?

I am trying to understand when I need to use auto launch and when I need use allow in background, from my understanding both doing same thing but I am confused about the correct use case of them.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open at Login - this opens the application when you log into the computer. It fully opens and is capable of doing everything the application does

Allow in the background - this allows the application to perform *limited* tasks while not fully open. This can be things like checking update server for updates. Updating it's status as per the date and time of the computer. Useful for things like calendars apps. Update messaging status

Comment: Is there a real example of putting app in background in swift that i could see and understand the limited tasks in swift?

Comment: @bulletproofsoftwareengineer Software development questions are off-topic on AD.

Comment: @nohillside: Yes Sir, You watching!